# Android SQLite Database: adding columns after DB is created

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm a bit unfamiliar with updating SQLite Databases after I have created them.  Is it relatively easy to add new columns and update values in the rows?  Like adding an email or twitter name column to a contact list app.  Or could I set up columns with the name "Col1, Col2, etc" to have extra for later and then when I want to use those columns add them into my queries/cursors in my app such that KEY_EMAIL is "Col15" or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite supports a limited subset of the ALTER TABLE command. You can rename a table or add a new column. So you can't rename or delete a column or remove constraints after you've created the table (at least not with sql-commands).

So, no need to add "spare"-columns. In fact, since you can't remove columns, that'd be a bad idea.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)